# Как в pandas данные из одного df положить в другой в цикле?

Tags: python, pandas, циклы

Код, который в тестовом виде работает:

```
# делаем .loc одного из столбцов равный значению
temp_df = df.loc[df['cat_number']=='5111-0395']
# обрезаем датафрейм нужным количеством столбцов (опционально)
temp_df = temp_df[['cat_number', 'date', 'DT']]
# сортируем по одному из столбцов
temp_df.sort_values('DT', ascending = True)
# берем последний и первый элементы в этом датафрейме и считаем разницу
diff = (temp_df.tail(1).date.values - temp_df.head(1).DT.values)
# из полученного diff типом timedelta получаем фактическое количество дней
diff = diff[0].days
# в датафрейме temp_df_c берем и обрезаем датафрейм по нужным нам значениям в выбранном столбце
temp_df_c = df_c.loc[df_c['cat_number']=='5111-0395']
# в столбец lifetime (не созданный до этого) кладем diff
temp_df_c['lifetime'] = diff
```

все ок, все работает.
Последней строчкой пандас сам создает столбец `lifetime`, в который кладет значение, содержащееся в `diff`

Переходим к циклу, который не работает:

```
# для каждого i-того уникального вхождения в столбце cat_number в датафрейме df
for i in df.cat_number.unique():
# сохраняем в temp_df обрезанный датафрейм с условием по столбцу cat_number, равным i
    temp_df = df[df['cat_number']==i].sort_values(['DT','date'], ascending = (True, True))
# получаем аналогичным образом diff
    diff = (temp_df.tail(1).date.values - temp_df.head(1).DT.values)
# приводим diff к удобному виду
    diff = diff[0].days
# в другой датафрейм df_c, обрезанный по условию в столбце cat_number, равному i, в новый (не созданный до этого) столбец кладем diff
    df_c[df_c['cat_number']==i]['lifetime'] = diff
```

вся эта штука с каждым новым `i` в цикле переписывает (каждый раз создает заново) столбец `lifetime`. Как мне применить `.append` тут (чтобы цикл не переписывал значение) я так и не понял. Поможете?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# необходимо заранее создать пустой столбец lifetime
df_c['lifetime'] = np.nan

# теперь обратите внимание на последнюю строчку в цикле
for i in df.cat_number.unique():
    temp_df = df[df['cat_number']==i].sort_values(['DT','date'], ascending = (True, True))
    diff = (temp_df.tail(1).date.values - temp_df.head(1).DT.values)
    diff = diff[0].days
    df_c.loc[df_c[df_c['cat_number']==i].index, 'lifetime'] = diff
```

Comment: Это что такое? Это ваш ответ на ваш же, только вам понятный вопрос?

Comment: Нет. Если вы внимательно посмотрите на последнюю строчку ответа, то вам станет очевидно, почему этот ответ меня устроил в итоге. Я специально показал временное решение, которое работало.

Comment: Если вы внимательно просмотрите на комментарий к вашему _вопросу_, то поймете, что внимательно смотреть на последнюю точку вашего ответа нет никакого желания, потому что кроме вас ваш вопрос никому не понятен.

Comment: В комментарии говорились о воспроизводимом df, что _не является необходимым_ для человека, понимающего устройство ссылок на строки и столбцы в пандас. Еще раз. Вопрос не в df, а в обращении к столбцам и строкам. Ну и да, ровно на этот вопрос был получен ответ в другом профильном обществе. Сюда сохранен ответ ровно для того, чтобы он хоть где-то остался. Других похожих на SO я не нашел, поэтому для сообщества это может оказаться полезным.

Comment: То есть, вы действительно не понимаете, что, несмотря на знание "устройства" ссылок, при неочевидном строении вашего датафрейма ваш вопрос никому, кроме вас, не понятен? Почитайте ссылку в комментарии к вашему вопросу. Мне можете не отвечать, эта беседа мне более не интересна.

Comment: see you. Повторюсь, в профильном сообществе по анализу данных ровно на такой же вопрос я смог получить ответ.